# Xcode Error "Expected '{' in body of function declaration"

Tags: swift

I have tried everything and I cannot figure out the error.

```
import Foundation
import Firebase

struct User {
    var email: String!
    var firstname: String
    var lastname: String
    var uid: String!
    var profilePictureUrl: String
    var country: String
    var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!
    var key: String = ""

    init(email: String, firstname: String, lastname: String, uid: String, profilePictureUrl: String, country: String) {
        self.email = email
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname
        self.profilePictureUrl = profilePictureUrl
        self.country = country
        self.ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    }

    func toAnyObject() -> [String: Any] {
        return ["email": email, "firstname": firstname, "lastname": lastname, "country": country, "uid": uid, "profilePictureUrl": profilePictureUrl]
    }
}
```

The error is in the function `toAnyObject`.

Comment: What version of Xcode? I don't get any errors for that code in the Xcode 8.3.2 playground (though I did remove the 3 Firebase related lines).

Comment: I have the most recent version of Xcode. I am in a project, using Firebase.

Comment: Since we're now deeply into a beta cycle, what do you mean by *the latest version*? The "latest" versions could mean *8.3.3* or *9 beta 3*. Could you please just give us the version number?

Comment: I'm in 8.3.3, sorry for not specifying.

Comment: What's your macOS version?

Comment: I'm not sure, however I don't see how that'd be an issue.

Comment: As I can build your code without any problem with Xcode 8.3.3 on macOS 10.12.5, in some (not many) cases macOS version may affect some behavior of Xcode. So just for confirmation.

Comment: Have you tried using static func?

Answer (score -1):

Your function return [String : Any]. However, Its value is not Any.It is possible to edit temporarily as easy to understand as follows.

```
func toAnyObject() -> [String: Any] {
        return ["email": email, "firstname": firstname, "lastname": lastname, "country": country, "uid": uid, "profilePictureUrl": profilePictureUrl] as [String : Any]
```

Hope it can help you fix issuse.